# Install packages with unmet dependencies

Tags: package-management, dependencies

I am trying to install some applications but some of them fail to install. The three applications I tried are Vim, Emacs and GNOME-Do. I am using Ubuntu 10.10 installed as a guest OS in VirtualBox. The kernel version installed is 2.6.35-26.

The error I got is :

```
alvinsim@ubuntu:/etc/apt$ sudo apt-get install emacs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
emacs : Depends: emacs23 or emacs23-lucid but it is not going to be installed
emacs23-nox but it is not going to be installed E: Broken packages
```

What is wrong and how do I fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you dump the apt sources using `find /etc/apt/ -name '*.list' -ls -exec cat {} \;` on http://paste.ubuntu.com/? This problem is likely caused by third party repositories.

Comment: The command output is at http://paste.ubuntu.com/566513/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the packages by following the steps provided by the ubuntu package manager trouble shooting procedure. I believed the previous packages were somehow broken.