# Unable to correct dependencies while installing vlc

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies, vlc

In an attempt to install vlc offline (internet was down), I manually installed the packages needed to run vlc. I copied the packages from my friends Ubuntu`(apt-cache depends vlc)`. So now my apt-get install seems to be broken.

I did try other articles, with no luck ([here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25930/install-packages-with-unmet-dependencies)).

**Output of sudo apt-get install vlc**

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libavcodec53 : Depends: libdirac-encoder0 but it is not installed
                Depends: libgsm1 (>= 1.0.13) but it is not installed
                Depends: libmp3lame0 but it is not installed
                Depends: libopenjpeg2 but it is not installed
                Depends: libschroedinger-1.0-0 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not installed
                Depends: libva1 (> 1.0.15~) but it is not installed
                Depends: libx264-123 but it is not installable
                Depends: libxvidcore4 (>= 1.2.2) but it is not installed
 libavcodec56 : Depends: libavresample2 (>= 6:11~beta1) but it is not installable
                Depends: libgsm1 (>= 1.0.13) but it is not installed
                Depends: libmp3lame0 but it is not installed
                Depends: libopenjpeg5 (>= 1.3+dfsg) but it is not installable
                Depends: libopus0 (>= 1.1) but it is not installed
                Depends: libschroedinger-1.0-0 (>= 1.0.7) but it is not installed
                Depends: libva1 (>= 1.0.3) but it is not installed
                Depends: libx264-142 but it is not installed
                Depends: libxvidcore4 (>= 1.2.2) but it is not installed
 libc6 : Breaks: locales (< 2.19) but 2.13+git20120306-12.1 is installed
         Breaks: libc6:i386 (!= 2.19-18) but 2.19-0ubuntu6.6 is installed
 libc6:i386 : Breaks: libc6 (!= 2.19-0ubuntu6.6) but 2.19-18 is installed
 libc6-dbg : Depends: libc6 (= 2.19-0ubuntu6.6) but 2.19-18 is installed
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc-dev-bin (= 2.19-18)
 libfreerdp-cache1.1 : Depends: libfreerdp-common1.1.0 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libfreerdp-primitives1.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libjpeg62-turbo (>= 1.3.1) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libwinpr-crt0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libwinpr-crypto0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libwinpr-dsparse0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libwinpr-environment0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libwinpr-file0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libwinpr-handle0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libwinpr-heap0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libwinpr-input0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libwinpr-interlocked0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libwinpr-library0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libwinpr-path0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libwinpr-pool0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libwinpr-registry0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libwinpr-synch0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libwinpr-sysinfo0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libwinpr-thread0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                       Breaks: libfreerdp1 (< 1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg-1) but 1.0.2-2ubuntu1 is installed
 libfreerdp-client1.1 : Depends: libfreerdp-common1.1.0 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                        Depends: libfreerdp-primitives1.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                        Depends: libjpeg62-turbo (>= 1.3.1) but it is not installable
                        Depends: libwinpr-crt0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                        Depends: libwinpr-crypto0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                        Depends: libwinpr-dsparse0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                        Depends: libwinpr-environment0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                        Depends: libwinpr-file0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                        Depends: libwinpr-handle0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                        Depends: libwinpr-heap0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                        Depends: libwinpr-input0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                        Depends: libwinpr-interlocked0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                        Depends: libwinpr-library0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                        Depends: libwinpr-path0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                        Depends: libwinpr-pool0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                        Depends: libwinpr-registry0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                        Depends: libwinpr-synch0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                        Depends: libwinpr-sysinfo0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                        Depends: libwinpr-thread0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                        Breaks: libfreerdp1 (< 1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg-1) but 1.0.2-2ubuntu1 is installed
 libfreerdp-codec1.1 : Depends: libfreerdp-primitives1.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libjpeg62-turbo (>= 1.3.1) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libwinpr-crt0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libwinpr-environment0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libwinpr-handle0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libwinpr-heap0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libwinpr-interlocked0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libwinpr-path0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libwinpr-pool0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libwinpr-registry0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libwinpr-synch0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libwinpr-sysinfo0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libwinpr-thread0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                       Breaks: libfreerdp1 (< 1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg-1) but 1.0.2-2ubuntu1 is installed
 libfreerdp-core1.1 : Depends: libfreerdp-common1.1.0 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                      Depends: libfreerdp-primitives1.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                      Depends: libjpeg62-turbo (>= 1.3.1) but it is not installable
                      Depends: libwinpr-crt0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                      Depends: libwinpr-crypto0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                      Depends: libwinpr-dsparse0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                      Depends: libwinpr-environment0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                      Depends: libwinpr-file0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                      Depends: libwinpr-handle0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                      Depends: libwinpr-heap0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                      Depends: libwinpr-input0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                      Depends: libwinpr-interlocked0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                      Depends: libwinpr-library0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                      Depends: libwinpr-path0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                      Depends: libwinpr-pool0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                      Depends: libwinpr-registry0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                      Depends: libwinpr-synch0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                      Depends: libwinpr-sysinfo0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                      Depends: libwinpr-thread0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                      Breaks: libfreerdp1 (< 1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg-1) but 1.0.2-2ubuntu1 is installed
 libfreerdp-crypto1.1 : Depends: libwinpr-crt0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                        Depends: libwinpr-crypto0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                        Depends: libwinpr-environment0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                        Depends: libwinpr-file0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                        Depends: libwinpr-handle0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                        Depends: libwinpr-heap0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                        Depends: libwinpr-interlocked0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                        Depends: libwinpr-library0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                        Depends: libwinpr-path0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                        Depends: libwinpr-registry0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                        Depends: libwinpr-synch0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                        Depends: libwinpr-sysinfo0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                        Depends: libwinpr-thread0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                        Breaks: libfreerdp1 (< 1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg-1) but 1.0.2-2ubuntu1 is installed
 libfreerdp-gdi1.1 : Depends: libfreerdp-common1.1.0 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                     Depends: libfreerdp-primitives1.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                     Depends: libjpeg62-turbo (>= 1.3.1) but it is not installable
                     Depends: libwinpr-crt0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                     Depends: libwinpr-crypto0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                     Depends: libwinpr-dsparse0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                     Depends: libwinpr-environment0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                     Depends: libwinpr-file0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                     Depends: libwinpr-handle0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                     Depends: libwinpr-heap0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                     Depends: libwinpr-input0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                     Depends: libwinpr-interlocked0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                     Depends: libwinpr-library0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                     Depends: libwinpr-path0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                     Depends: libwinpr-pool0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                     Depends: libwinpr-registry0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                     Depends: libwinpr-synch0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                     Depends: libwinpr-sysinfo0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                     Depends: libwinpr-thread0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                     Breaks: libfreerdp1 (< 1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg-1) but 1.0.2-2ubuntu1 is installed
 libfreerdp-locale1.1 : Depends: libwinpr-crt0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                        Depends: libwinpr-environment0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                        Depends: libwinpr-handle0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                        Depends: libwinpr-heap0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                        Depends: libwinpr-input0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                        Depends: libwinpr-interlocked0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                        Depends: libwinpr-path0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                        Depends: libwinpr-synch0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                        Depends: libwinpr-sysinfo0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                        Depends: libwinpr-thread0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                        Breaks: libfreerdp1 (< 1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg-1) but 1.0.2-2ubuntu1 is installed
 libfreerdp-rail1.1 : Depends: libwinpr-crt0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                      Depends: libwinpr-environment0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                      Depends: libwinpr-handle0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                      Depends: libwinpr-heap0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                      Depends: libwinpr-interlocked0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                      Depends: libwinpr-path0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                      Depends: libwinpr-synch0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                      Depends: libwinpr-sysinfo0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                      Depends: libwinpr-thread0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                      Breaks: libfreerdp1 (< 1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg-1) but 1.0.2-2ubuntu1 is installed
 libfreerdp-utils1.1 : Depends: libwinpr-crt0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libwinpr-environment0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libwinpr-handle0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libwinpr-heap0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libwinpr-interlocked0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libwinpr-path0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libwinpr-synch0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libwinpr-sysinfo0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                       Depends: libwinpr-thread0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                       Breaks: libfreerdp1 (< 1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg-1) but 1.0.2-2ubuntu1 is installed
 libfreetype6 : Breaks: libfreetype6:i386 (!= 2.5.2-3) but 2.5.2-1ubuntu2.4 is installed
 libfreetype6:i386 : Breaks: libfreetype6 (!= 2.5.2-1ubuntu2.4) but 2.5.2-3 is installed
 libfreetype6-dev : Depends: libpng-dev
 libgcc1 : Depends: gcc-4.9-base (= 4.9.2-10) but 4.9.1-0ubuntu1 is installed
           Breaks: libgcc1:i386 (!= 1:4.9.2-10) but 1:4.9.1-0ubuntu1 is installed
 libgcc1:i386 : Breaks: libgcc1 (!= 1:4.9.1-0ubuntu1) but 1:4.9.2-10 is installed
 libice6 : Breaks: libice6:i386 (!= 2:1.0.9-1+b1) but 2:1.0.8-2 is installed
 libice6:i386 : Breaks: libice6 (!= 2:1.0.8-2) but 2:1.0.9-1+b1 is installed
 libqt4-declarative : Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1) but 4:4.8.2+dfsg-11 is installed
                      Depends: libqtgui4 (= 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1) but 4:4.8.2+dfsg-11 is installed
 libqt4-designer : Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1) but 4:4.8.2+dfsg-11 is installed
                   Depends: libqtgui4 (= 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1) but 4:4.8.2+dfsg-11 is installed
 libqt4-help : Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1) but 4:4.8.2+dfsg-11 is installed
               Depends: libqtgui4 (= 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1) but 4:4.8.2+dfsg-11 is installed
 libqt4-network : Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1) but 4:4.8.2+dfsg-11 is installed
 libqt4-opengl : Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1) but 4:4.8.2+dfsg-11 is installed
                 Depends: libqtgui4 (= 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1) but 4:4.8.2+dfsg-11 is installed
 libqt4-script : Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1) but 4:4.8.2+dfsg-11 is installed
 libqt4-scripttools : Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1) but 4:4.8.2+dfsg-11 is installed
                      Depends: libqtgui4 (= 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1) but 4:4.8.2+dfsg-11 is installed
 libqt4-sql : Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1) but 4:4.8.2+dfsg-11 is installed
 libqt4-sql-sqlite : Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1) but 4:4.8.2+dfsg-11 is installed
 libqt4-svg : Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1) but 4:4.8.2+dfsg-11 is installed
              Depends: libqtgui4 (= 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1) but 4:4.8.2+dfsg-11 is installed
 libqt4-test : Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1) but 4:4.8.2+dfsg-11 is installed
 libqt4-xml : Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1) but 4:4.8.2+dfsg-11 is installed
 libqt4-xmlpatterns : Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1) but 4:4.8.2+dfsg-11 is installed
 libqtcore4 : Breaks: libqtcore4:i386 (!= 4:4.8.2+dfsg-11) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is installed
 libqtcore4:i386 : Breaks: libqtcore4 (!= 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1) but 4:4.8.2+dfsg-11 is installed
 libqtdbus4 : Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1) but 4:4.8.2+dfsg-11 is installed
 libqtgui4 : Depends: libmng1 (>= 1.0.10) but it is not installable
             Depends: libtiff4 (> 3.9.5-3~) but it is not installable
             Breaks: libqtgui4:i386 (!= 4:4.8.2+dfsg-11) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1 is installed
 libqtgui4:i386 : Breaks: libqtgui4 (!= 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1) but 4:4.8.2+dfsg-11 is installed
 libqtwebkit4 : Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.4) but 4:4.8.2+dfsg-11 is installed
 libsdl-image1.2 : Depends: libtiff4 (> 3.9.5-3~) but it is not installable
                   Depends: libwebp2 but it is not installable
 libsdl1.2debian : Depends: libdirectfb-1.2-9 but it is not installed
 libsm6 : Breaks: libsm6:i386 (!= 2:1.2.2-1+b1) but 2:1.2.1-2 is installed
 libsm6:i386 : Breaks: libsm6 (!= 2:1.2.1-2) but 2:1.2.2-1+b1 is installed
 libstdc++6 : Depends: gcc-4.9-base (= 4.9.2-10) but 4.9.1-0ubuntu1 is installed
              Breaks: libstdc++6:i386 (!= 4.9.2-10) but 4.8.2-19ubuntu1 is installed
 libstdc++6:i386 : Breaks: libstdc++6 (!= 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) but 4.9.2-10 is installed
 libstdc++6-4.7-dev : Depends: gcc-4.7-base (= 4.7.2-5) but it is not installed
                      Depends: g++-4.7 (= 4.7.2-5) but it is not installed
 libva-x11-1 : Depends: libva1 (>= 1.0.6) but it is not installed
 libwinpr-rpc0.1 : Breaks: libfreerdp1 (< 1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg-1) but 1.0.2-2ubuntu1 is installed
 libwinpr-sspi0.1 : Depends: libwinpr-crt0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                    Depends: libwinpr-crypto0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                    Depends: libwinpr-handle0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                    Depends: libwinpr-interlocked0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                    Depends: libwinpr-registry0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                    Depends: libwinpr-synch0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                    Depends: libwinpr-sysinfo0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                    Depends: libwinpr-thread0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                    Breaks: libfreerdp1 (< 1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg-1) but 1.0.2-2ubuntu1 is installed
 libwinpr-utils0.1 : Depends: libwinpr-crt0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                     Depends: libwinpr-handle0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                     Depends: libwinpr-interlocked0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                     Depends: libwinpr-synch0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                     Depends: libwinpr-sysinfo0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                     Depends: libwinpr-thread0.1 (>= 1.1.0~beta1+git20130629) but it is not installable
                     Breaks: libfreerdp1 (< 1.1.0~git20140921.1.440916e+dfsg-1) but 1.0.2-2ubuntu1 is installed
 libx11-6 : Breaks: libx11-6:i386 (!= 2:1.6.2-3) but 2:1.6.2-1ubuntu2 is installed
 libx11-6:i386 : Breaks: libx11-6 (!= 2:1.6.2-1ubuntu2) but 2:1.6.2-3 is installed
 libxcb1 : Breaks: libxcb1:i386 (!= 1.10-3+b1) but 1.10-2ubuntu1 is installed
 libxcb1:i386 : Breaks: libxcb1 (!= 1.10-2ubuntu1) but 1.10-3+b1 is installed
 libxext6 : Breaks: libxext6:i386 (!= 2:1.3.3-1) but 2:1.3.2-1ubuntu0.0.14.04.1 is installed
 libxext6:i386 : Breaks: libxext6 (!= 2:1.3.2-1ubuntu0.0.14.04.1) but 2:1.3.3-1 is installed
 libxinerama1 : Breaks: libxinerama1:i386 (!= 2:1.1.3-1+b1) but 2:1.1.3-1 is installed
 libxinerama1:i386 : Breaks: libxinerama1 (!= 2:1.1.3-1) but 2:1.1.3-1+b1 is installed
 phonon-backend-vlc : Depends: libphonon4 (>= 4:4.6.0.0) but it is not installed
 qdbus : Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4.1) but 4:4.8.2+dfsg-11 is installed
 qtcore4-l10n : Breaks: libqtcore4 (< 4:4.8.5+dfsg-1~) but 4:4.8.2+dfsg-11 is installed
 vlc : Depends: libva1 (> 1.0.15~) but it is not installed
 vlc-nox : Depends: libass4 (>= 0.9.7) but it is not installed
           Depends: libdirac-decoder0 but it is not installed
           Depends: libdirac-encoder0 but it is not installed
           Depends: libdirectfb-1.2-9 but it is not installed
           Depends: libdvbpsi7 (>= 0.2.0) but it is not installable
           Depends: libdvdnav4 (>= 4.2.0+20120524) but it is not installed
           Depends: libdvdread4 but it is not installed
           Depends: libebml3 but it is not installable
           Depends: libfaad2 (>= 2.7) but it is not installed
           Depends: libiso9660-8 (>= 0.83) but it is not installed
           Depends: libkate1 (>= 0.3.0) but it is not installed
           Depends: liblua5.1-0 but it is not installed
           Depends: libmad0 (>= 0.15.1b-3) but it is not installed
           Depends: libmatroska5 but it is not installable
           Depends: libmodplug1 but it is not installed
           Depends: libmpcdec6 (>= 1:0.1~r435) but it is not installed
           Depends: libmpeg2-4 but it is not installed
           Depends: libpostproc52 (>= 6:0.8.3-1~) but it is not installed
           Depends: libproxy0 (>= 0.2.3) but it is not installable
           Depends: libresid-builder0c2a but it is not installed
           Depends: libschroedinger-1.0-0 (>= 1.0.10) but it is not installed
           Depends: libsidplay2 but it is not installed
           Depends: libswscale2 (>= 6:0.8.3-1~) but it is not installed
           Depends: libtwolame0 but it is not installed
           Depends: libudev0 (>= 146) but it is not installable
           Depends: libupnp6 (>= 1.4.3) but it is not installed
           Depends: libvcdinfo0 (>= 0.7.21) but it is not installed
           Depends: libx264-123 but it is not installable
           Depends: libzvbi0 (>= 0.2.11) but it is not installed
 zlib1g : Breaks: zlib1g:i386 (!= 1:1.2.8.dfsg-2+b1) but 1:1.2.8.dfsg-1ubuntu1 is installed
 zlib1g:i386 : Breaks: zlib1g (!= 1:1.2.8.dfsg-1ubuntu1) but 1:1.2.8.dfsg-2+b1 is installed
```

Answer (score 0):

You have fallen in package mess, perhaps, you have manually installed different incompatible versions of packages even for different architectures. **Remove these packages. Use one repository instead.**

Ok, if you have no internet, you can download them at your friend's - ***from one repository*** - I recommend the official http://packages.ubuntu.com/ Choose your version of Ubuntu and get them.